# Would this effect occur if an ice planet was put into orbit or trajectory?

Tags: planet, orbit, earth

Imagine an earth getting warmer. Humans decide to make their homes ready for a voluntary ice age. All the space agencies work together to get an icy planet/moon into our orbit between us and the sun.

My theory is that because the sun is heating up the ice and blowing it in the direction of earth, it'll make the Earth colder.

That final part is my question: Could ice molten in space eventually reach earth and perhaps be pushed in that direction by its heat?? Not taking into account whether or not it would benefit the earth.

I'm an amateur with no knowledge of physics, chemistry and astrology and want to learn answers to my questions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this would do better on space.stackexchange.com or worldbuilding.stackexchange.com -- probably world building, on SE's like this you get the super smart guys and experts who know how to do feasible things. In world building you get people who like to think about what we can accomplish given infinite resources. If you're asking about bringing a comet into orbit or something, that's a bit more realistic, but it probably wouldn't have a massive effect like an ice age.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *purely* hypothetical questions are off topic. see the [help]. You can't get move an icy planet into orbit inside the orbit of the Earth, the amount of Energy involved is too great.  Worldbuilding might consider your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange! I'm a little confused about your question, but I'll answer it the best to my ability.

First of all, I would like to state that such scenario is near impossible because getting the planet there would be extremely difficult.

Second of all, when the ice is being "blown", it would have to be perfectly aligned with the Earth not just in its position in orbit, but also in its angle of orbit.

Third of all, the ice would have to travel probably hundreds of kilometres, meaning that it would either 1) not make it by getting in orbit around the Sun / melting or 2) get lost in space.

The heat of the Sun can barely move things at all - I assume you're sort of thinking of a Light Sail, but that's light, and ice would be too heavy anyway.

Getting the ice off of there would also be challenging because its connected to the planet, and can't just be "lifted" by heat. That's why the Earth's surface doesn't float / scrape away by the Sun's heat.

Overall, I do not think it would be possible.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That answer provided all the information I needed. I'll mark as answered, but will still keep an eye on this thread